# how to create android linearlayout with RTL horizontal orientation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want to create a linear layout with horizontal orientation

but I want it to position its children aligned to its right and not to its left as usual

how can I do this?

I know how to do this using relativeLayout, but I want to practice linearLayout

Comment: why You can't use RelativeLayouts?

Comment: I know how to do this using relativeLayout, but I want to practice linearLayout

Comment: I see. The only way is to do it programmatically. Since those are stacked from left to the right, you can simply invert the order. But as I said you need to do it programmatically

Comment: I meant alignment wise, not order wise

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use android:layoutDirection attribute which is introduced in 4.2(jelly bean).

The following links will help.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: I tried the solution for android prior to 4.2 in second link: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html however it throwghs an error: "Error: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute" I think this solution is inapplicable

Comment: as the link suggests; the RTL support is available in 4.2, not prior.

Answer (score 9):

if you are using Android studio you can do this:

1- right click on the project main folder

2- refactor

3- add support for RTL

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code snippet to reverse your layout views.

```
LinearLayout ll = // inflate
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
for(int x = 0; x < ll.getChildCount(); x++) {
    views.add(ll.getChildAt(x));
}
ll.removeAllViews();
for(int x = views.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    ll.addView(views.get(x));
}
```

OR
To begin supporting RTL layouts in your app, set the android:supportsRtl attribute to the  element in your manifest file and set it “true". Once you enable this, the system will enable various RTL APIs to display your app with RTL layouts. For instance, the action bar will show the icon and title on the right side and action buttons on the left, and any layouts you’ve created with the framework-provided View classes will also be reversed.
[Look at this android doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)

Comment: Amazing tweek, i didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set on the parent view element's gravity to right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" <!-- make sure this is not wrap_content !-->
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"/>

</LinearLayout
```

Comment: Worked for me just fine